# Command line script error in Azure devops pipeline

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, powerapps

Am getting the following error message in cmd line script while runing the pipeline in azure devops.

> error: src refspec main does not match any error: failed to push some
> refs to
> 'https://dev.azure.com/DevendraPadhi/Project%20D/_git/Project%20D
>
> error: pathspec 'main' did not match any file(s) known to git fatal:
> Cannot prompt because user interactivity has been disabled. fatal:
> Cannot prompt because user interactivity has been disabled. fatal:
> could not read Password for
> 'https://DevendraPadhi@dev.azure.com/DevendraPadhi/Project
> D/_git/Project D': terminal prompts disabled

PLease help to overcome this

[image: Commanad line script (GIT)]

[image: Azure pipeline Error message for Command line script]

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

How to Push Back to TFVC(Other steps are similar, the only different thing is the last step.):

```
tf add * /recursive /noprompt  /loginType:OAuth /login:.,$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN

tf checkin * /comment:"xxx" /recursive /noprompt  /loginType:OAuth /login:.,$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
```

Successfully on my side:

[image]

[image]

**Original Answer:**

I can reproduce your issue:

[image]

The operations that Shamrai suggested is needed, but not enough.

You need 3 steps:

***Step1, allow script to access OAuth token***

[image]

***Step2, give contribute permission to build service account.***

[image]

[image]

***Step3, use this commands to push back changes:***

`git push origin HEAD:main`

(Please notice add the ***HEAD:***)

Comment: If we want to use TFVC repo then what commands, needs to use

Comment: @devendar Hi Devendar, I updated the correct usage of TFVC in my answer, please be sure to reply whether it works on your side after reading and testing. If it works, please [mark it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLVLd.png), this will help others who meet the similar issue. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I unable to mark it, its shows the following error while mark it.error message __________"  You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded. "______________

Comment: @devendar Just want to confirm if my answer answered your question? And by the way, mark the answer doesn't means upvote the answer, it means this operation(Accept answer): https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers , this action is only used when you are the questioner and are sure that an answer answers your question. The action is click the [tick button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjDO1.png).

Comment: I am getting the following error, pls help me.

Comment: TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com/DevendraPadhi.
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '100'.

Comment: The following script I used                                                                          tf add * /recursive /noprompt  /loginType:OAuth /login:.,$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN

tf checkin * /comment:"xxx" /recursive /noprompt  /loginType:OAuth /login:.,$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN

Comment: the HEAD: tidbit was the missing thing for me this whole time.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Do you follow this doc?: [Run Git commands in a script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic).

Check this option in your build definition:

[image]

Comment: this is fine, Now I can able to run the pipeline, if we want to use TFVC repo then what commands, needs to use ?